# Getting Array of string literals from Typescript interface type

Tags: typescript, types

I currently have  type that is equal to the following interfaces:

```
type T = a_1_0_0 | a_1_1_0

interface a_1_0_0 = { v:'a_1_0_0',...other stuff}
interface a_1_1_0 = {v:'a_1_1_0', ... other stuff}
```

Now I have a parameter in a function:

```
function func(foo: T) {

}
```

where foo resolves to the type: `'a_1_1_0' | 'a_1_0_0' | undefined`

is there a way to check to see if var `foo` is in the set `'a_1_1_0' | 'a_1_0_0'`

foo is being treated as a string in the current implementation

minimal repro example:

```
type T = a_1_0_0 | a_1_1_0;

interface a_1_0_0  { v:'a_1_0_0'};
interface a_1_1_0  {v:'a_1_1_0'};

function func(foo: T['v']) {

}

const foo = 'a_0_0_0' // invalid interface type
func(foo);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UCGB9AjCgDFqAfZ6hmA3ALABQFAlgHbAQBOAZkgMbSobaZRQDeUAG4AuAOScsWUQF8y5WvWZsOhLrz4jxqqbIoUmAVxqtgVAPY0oh4wAomZs8NgBtUYNEBdAJT895aX6sFgDOwFYOCFBa3FJQAPRxULSCSAA2VAAmSXSMLOxQoJD6Rqx2Dl7EQA)

im aware that the compiler states that it is invalid, however my current implementation sets the variable at runtime so there are no compile issues

Comment: Instead of pseudocode, could you post a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when someone drops it into an IDE?  As asked I'd say you just do `function foo: (T["v"])` but it's hard to tell without testable code.

Comment: @jcalz I have added a playgroud and minimal repro example

Comment: Sorry, what is your issue?  It looks like the example code from the playground is behaving exactly as desired, so there's no problem at all.  Or maybe you do have a problem with your current implementation, but I can't see that.  All I see is the code you post here.  Could you make a [mre] that demonstrates your actual problem?  Clearly?  Like, there should be code that does not error where you expect it to, or code that does error where you expect it not to, or some other undesirable or unexpected behavior that other people can see for themselves.